# PHP -> python seems to not work on web server

Tags: php, python, html, pdf

I have a few pages (one html, one php, and one python script) that takes a user input, and then outputs a pdf file (using reportlab) for the user. When I test on apache (localhost), it works perfectly.
However, online on a real web host it is not working. The version of PHP on the web server is 5.2.17 and python is installed.

Could the version be an issue? I am very lost because I'm not very experienced and it works perfectly on Apache and not at all on the internet.

Last thing, the command I use to call the python function from php is this:

```
$ed = exec("python pdfgeneration2.py $name $age");
```

I also thought maybe there is a better command for this?

My question may be vague and unclear but if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by switching to something a bit more robust, like http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php depending on whether you need to read and write to the command, or just read the output.  Moreover, my first suspicion would be that the python binary is not in your webserver user's path.  Try adding the full path like `/full/path/to/python pdfgeneration2.py $name $age`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try all of these suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at /var/logs/httpd/error_log, or wherever your distro's apache stores logs.  Odds are you'll find an error message there from PHP.
2. In addition to checking the path like sberry recommended, double check perms, too.  Apache will need execute permissions on the python script:  `chown apache:apache pdfgeneration2.py`